# In Bash how would I sum lines that have the same value in column 2

Tags: bash

Example of what I'm looking to do

if the source information resembled this

```
blah,445522-000,6
nug,382911-003,2
slug,445522-000,3
```

I know I can use `sort -t',' -g -k 2 (source file)` to sort based upon column 2 but what I really need to do is combine the first and third line
by combining them and summing column 3

output

```
nug,382911-003,2
blah,445522-000,9
```

not sure how to proceed any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use `awk` and make arrays whose keys are `$2`.

Comment: One array can contain the value in column 1, another array contains a sum of column 3.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '     {a[$2]+=$3} 
               !($2 in b){b[$2]=$1} 
               END       {for(k in a) print b[k],k,a[k]}' file

nug,382911-003,2
blah,445522-000,9
```

Comment: Thank you very much I got pulled on another project and will have to test this later tonigh